# Is there any way to locate the tabs on the left hand side of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk

I followed the [android developers tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) successfully created the tabs. But seems there is no straight forward way to locate the **tabs** on the **left hand side** of device screen.

Is there anybody know a way to implement left hand side tabs?? Is there any guideline about this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.  I've searched too for right-to-left support, but there's no such thing in Android.

What i did is to manipulate the code so the user will feel like its right to left - 
I've created 3 tabs in the XML, and added to my activity the code:

```
    final TabHost tabs = (TabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    final Resources resources = this.getResources();

    // third tab (first from left)
    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag3");
    spec.setContent(R.id.aboutImg);
    spec.setIndicator(this.getString(R.string.title_about), resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.id));
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    // second tab
    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.listfav);
    spec.setIndicator(this.getString(R.string.title_favorites), resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.bdge));
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    // first tab
    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.viewflipper);
    spec.setIndicator(this.getString(R.string.title_main), resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.cab));
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    tabs.setCurrentTab(2);
```

Pay attantion for the last line - im setting the current tab to be the last one - first from right.